# Lambda creates duplicate records in S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have Lambda function triggered by SQS. It does some verification on the received JSON object and writes it to a S3 bucket. Everything seems to work fine, except that when looking at all versions of the object in the bucket with versioning enabled, it seems that, every now and then, it saves a double. It's the same object with same contents, same time of save, but a different version ID. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your SQS queue type set to FIFO or Standard?

Comment: Standard. Since it's triggering Lambda it can't be FIFO is my understanding.

Comment: @Ivars it is very relevant that you can sometimes duplicate this by invoking the function manually, as you mentioned below -- that rules out SQS.  Every time you create an object in S3, the version-id of the new object is provided in the response.  As a starting point in your troubleshooting... log that value.

Answer (score 1):

AWS SQS Standard Queue's guarantee that each item will be delivered at least once, but makes no guarantees of duplicate deliveries.

So in certain cases SQS might deliver the same payload multiple times when using standard queues. This is why you are seeing duplicate versions in your S3 bucket.

The [AWS SQS Queue Types page](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/features/) has some great descriptions of this and how it behaves.

From that page for `Standard Queues`:

> At-Least-Once Delivery: A message is delivered at least once, but occasionally more than one copy of a message is delivered.

Comment: I don't think that's it. Was my first thought as well, but same thing happens when I simply run a test with test event triggering Lambda instead of SQS,

Comment: @Ivars Then without more information we really can’t help.

Comment: Are you deleting the message via the `MessageHandle` after the message has been processed? Do the logs show any failures (eg a timeout) that might have led to the function running twice?